# How to change the font attributes and position of JSON data?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am newbie to web page designing. Well now i am working with JSON. And yeah, I am doing my own project for a quote machine for freecodecamp. The thing is i am able to display JSON data to my `<div>`.But how do I edit the font attributes and position of the JSON data that is appearing. I also attaching the js script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn").on('click',function(){
   $.ajaxSetup ({cache:false});
       $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&callback=", function(data) {
      $(".message").html(data[0].content + " — " + data[0].title);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to add css style to change the look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the css of the element after setting the content:

```
$(".message").css({'font-family':'Arial', 'left':'19px'});
```

Or alternatively you could use a CSS class to achieve the same result:

```
.message {
   font-family: 'Arial'; //or whatever font you want
   left: 19px; //or whatever positioning css changes need to be made.
}
```

The better way is using CSS to style the elements.

Comment: Well i already tried that part.Sry that i didn't mention it. That commands changes my div box as .messgae is its class. Not the JSON data

Comment: It seems like you are wanting to change the POSITION and FONT of the displayed data, is that not what you are asking?